# pip3 install discord-py-slash-command don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

[after the pip3 install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR1mx.png)  [Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVWiO.png)
I'm working on a discord.py ticket system, but the  `pip3 install discord-py-slash-command` doesn't work.
How do I resolve it?

Comment: Please give more information. What OS are you using? Why is the command not working? Please show what output you receive when you run the command. (I've just installed the command successfully on my computer)

Comment: i install the pip3 in os (i've tried in the os of visual studio and the cmd) and the program tell me "pip3 install discord-py-slash-command successful" but i restart visual studio code and i have the same problem

Comment: You still haven't said what operating system you're using or shown the actual error

Comment: I'm unsure what issue you're actually having. Is the package not installing or is it just not showing in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see from your image that you are using

```
from discord_slash import slashCommand
```

This is not the correct import statement. I assume you're following a tutorial: it appears that the has changed significantly between versions. You may benefit from looking at the official quickstart guide([link](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html))

Comment: the link you send me is a old version and the slah_command is a library of the button
(i use windows 10)

Comment: The link I sent is to the latest version of the documentation, from the PyPI page. I've also looked at an old version of the package which showed documentation more similar to your code. As I said, you may be following an outdated tutorial.

Comment: i don't follow a tutorial, now i'm tryning to use the discord_components but he tell me a error "NoneType" objet has no attribute 'default_role'